# Questions on writing: should I ask them in here or in writers.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, site-crossover

Recently, I find that in the writers.SE, there is a [academic tag](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing). Its description says:

> Writing texts in a scientific or educational setting: peer-reviewed articles, theses, text books, and others.

I think that it is completely overlap with this academia.SE site. So if I have a question about writing, which site will I get the best answers if I ask in? Can I cross-duplicate my question to get the best from both worlds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that Writers.SE is a better place to ask about general style and grammar, while Academia.SE is a better place to ask about substance and academic customs.

There's a big grey area where a question might legitimately be asked on either (e.g., these [two](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20046/switching-between-active-and-passive-voice) [questions](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14266/what-voice-active-passive-is-most-suitable-for-literary-academic-papers-liter) on active vs. passive voice).
Do *not* however, post a question on both: that is considered a Bad Thing on SE sites.  Pick the one you think will give you the best answer, and your question can be migrated to the other if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to academic writing, several SE sites other than Academia.SE might give you a good answer, at least *in principle*: Writers.SE or, even, for the usage of English, ELU.SE and ELL.SE.

I'm a bit hesitating, however, in suggesting to ask there questions about academic writing in technical fields (in case you are from a technical field) because I have the impression that there are not many academics who participate in the sites I've listed, especially from technical fields.