# No “academic writing” tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I was just editing tags for a question with only the “untagged” tag, and I noticed that there doesn’t seem to be an “academic-writing” tag. Given that a number of our questions seem to be about the process and contents of academic writing, this seems to be an oversight; I’m wondering if it was deliberate, or if we should create an “academic-writing” tag to cover these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there is a [writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag already, with the description:

> Academic writing is intended for a critical and informed audience, based on closely investigated knowledge, and posits ideas or arguments.

Would "academic-writing" be a better name or synonym for this tag? Given the nature of the site, I'm inclined to think that the "academic" qualifier is implied. After all, questions about non-academic writing wouldn't be on-topic here.

Comment: Don't see any reason not to make it a synonym

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [cag51's answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4633/20058), there is also a [writing-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) tag. I think that the two tags cover the range of questions we get here about academic writing.

We can maybe create the tag synonyms "academic-writing" and "academic-writing-style" (for symmetry). However, the [writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag has already the synonym [scientific-writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-writing). I'm not particularly keen on having a proliferation of tags, maybe it's better to rationalize a bit on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Also on writing.SE, we handle writing questions, including academic ones, technical writing ones, and other non-fiction,  so migrating to that site may be a useful option? (Not like Writing has any mods left, of course.)

Comment: Hi, we discussed this possibility in [this meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1550/20058). Maybe you can post a contribution also there on the basis of your experience on Writing SE.